# Software to monitor my bandwidth capacity over time

Tags: network-monitor, internet

In France, I used to use [Grenouille](http://grenouille.com/index.php) to monitor my [bandwidth capacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_%28computing%29#Network_bandwidth_capacity) over time. It's free but it used to under-assess my bandwidth when I was using it a few years ago. Furthermore both the website and software are in French only, and the application is restricted to French ISP.

So, what are some good applications to monitor my bandwidth capacity over time? I'm interested in applications for any OS (Win/Mac/Linux/Android/iPhone, but mostly interested in Windows right now). Basically it would do a [speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net/) every X minutes (+ ideally a [pingtest](http://www.pingtest.net/)), but I don't want to have anything to script/cron myself (or as little as possible).

Answer (score 6):

I will recommend you [Net Speed Monitor](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Bandwidth-Tools/NetSpeedMonitor.shtml). I jumped on it after using NetWorx for some time. It is not as powerful as NetWorx. But, its simplicity is why I liked it.

[image: Screenshot of Net Speed Monitor in Windows taskbar]

Looks very clean on the taskbar. The popup menu shows monthly and daily stats. Taskbar font settings are changeable

[image: Screenshot #1 of Net Speed Monitor user interface]

Shows process consuming internet
[image: Screenshot #2 of Net Speed Monitor user interface]

Show net usage daily or monthly. You can also export/import this data

**Update:** Currently it doesn't support Windows 8 but you be able to run it properly on Windows 10 by running it in compatibility mode.

Comment: +1, I use NetSpeedMonitor today and it's pretty solid.  The only reason I'm looking for something else is that NetSpeedMonitor can only monitor one NIC at a time.  Other than that, it's great.

Comment: I don't think  Net Speed Monitor  monitors  the bandwidth capacity over time.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt bandwidth capacity? What do you mean?

Comment: @VarunAgw https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_%28computing%29#Network_bandwidth_capacity

Comment: I no longer see that application listed on the developer's website or on their GitHub page.  Do you have a working link?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Replaced the link with Softpedia.

Comment: Thanks Varun.  Would you agree that the software is likely no longer being developed, but that the existing version works well?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Yes. Seems like the case from years.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [NetWorx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/). Simple to use and logs everything.

> NetWorx is a simple and free, yet powerful tool that helps you objectively evaluate your bandwidth situation. You can use it to collect bandwidth usage data and measure the speed of your Internet or any other network connection. NetWorx can help you identify possible sources of network problems, ensure that you do not exceed the bandwidth limits specified by your ISP, or track down suspicious network activity characteristic of Trojan horses and hacker attacks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does that record speed or just usage?

Comment: @NickWilde Both.

Comment: AFAIR NetWorx doesn't log the [bandwidth capacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_%28computing%29#Network_bandwidth_capacity) over time, right?

Comment: @iKlsR: The question is about a software that measures your maximum possible network speed. It usually measures that by receiving/sending enormous random data to a known host, and calculating how much went through in what time.

Comment: I just installed NetWorx. It is not showing any status like those you showed in the screenshots. Do I need to configure it ? If yes how ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this program that I made.   You use it much like ping except it returns Kbs speed instead of latency.

http://florian.ca/pingb

In your scenario best bet it to point it at your nearest internet gateway.

Comment: This answer seems a bit limited however I can't really say any specific things that should be added. Better to be a bit more detailed rather than relying on the link even though it is the official link of the tool. For this question that is probably enough. (although it looks to me like this will check once when run not at x intervals as requested in the answer?)

Comment: Thanks, do you know some good (=fast + respond to pings > 1.5KB) public IPs I can use? I'd like to test beyond my gateway.

Comment: kernel.org, centos.org, sites like that ... but also get the latest version (uploaded now) it will try to auto-detect your internet gateways with -a parameter.  That should help you too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [Neubot](http://www.neubot.org/download):

- Gratis
- open source: https://github.com/neubot/neubot

> The program runs in the background and periodically performs transmission tests with test servers, hosted by the distributed Measurement Lab platform, and (in future) with other instances of the program itself. Transmission tests probe the Internet using various application level protocols and test results are saved both locally and on the test servers. The results dataset contains samples from various Providers and is published on the web, allowing anyone to analyze the data for research purposes.

FAQ: https://github.com/neubot/neubot/blob/master/doc/faq.md

Neubot has a web interface to view the test results:

[image]

Comment: "This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only."

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 bummer :/

Answer (score 0):

[Net Speed Meter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/net-speed-meter/9nmbx01pxz4l?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) free download for Windows.