# Software to determine how much GB of data is consuming per month

Tags: windows, network-monitor

I have a Windows 7 PC and a broadband connection at my home. I have a iBall modem at home. I need a software to determine the amount of data am using each month. Specifications are -

1. It should be free.
2. It should be accurate, that is it should generate the maximum possible accurate result of data usage.
3. It should be a light software.
4. My PC has admin and guest accounts. Am the admin of my PC. So the software should work on both these accounts (like antivirus. They are installed by admin and works in all accounts of the system).

Can anyone suggest me a good software ?

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1658/software-to-monitor-my-bandwidth-capacity-over-time?rq=1